# Gradle parsing file IndexOutOfRangeException error building after upgrading to Unity 2022 + Vuforia 10.17.0

Tags: vuforia

Upgrading to:
Latest Unity 2022LTS
Vuforia 10.17.0

Building, I get this message:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser+<>c.<FromString>b__3_1 (System.String v) (at <495be959d8de4b98a0b655f3d7e76c85>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (TSource[] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) (at <da2c421c5cee4c5abffcb37d07c3a87c>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) (at <da2c421c5cee4c5abffcb37d07c3a87c>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector) (at <da2c421c5cee4c5abffcb37d07c3a87c>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser.FromString (System.String content) (at <495be959d8de4b98a0b655f3d7e76c85>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser.FromFile (System.String path) (at <495be959d8de4b98a0b655f3d7e76c85>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PostProcessAndroidBuild.ParseGradleProperties (System.String projectPath) (at <495be959d8de4b98a0b655f3d7e76c85>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PostProcessAndroidBuild.OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject (System.String path) (at <495be959d8de4b98a0b655f3d7e76c85>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.ProcessGenerateProjectCallbacks.OnGeneratePlatformProjectPostprocess (System.String path, System.Boolean strict) (at <950249aad035483681d10b4c9c3c20d4>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:190)
```

My gradle file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx**JVM_HEAP_SIZE**M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableR8=**MINIFY_WITH_R_EIGHT**
unityStreamingAssets=.unity3d**STREAMING_ASSETS**
**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Tried to change it the gradle.properties file, but I get always the same result.

- Adding-removing endfile new line.
- Removing **STREAMING_ASSETS** just in case it had any parsing error.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a **known issue** being addressed by the Vuforia Team.
You can follow here the resolution on Github: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/77

Meanwhile there is also a workaround, but does not seem to work on all cases. I will update my answer as soon we get a release with the fix